# Google Maps Javascript API reporting I'm over limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Javascript API is reporting that I'm over the limit, but I'm pretty sure I'm not. I get this error: 
`You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.  For more information on usage limits and the Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage`

My Google API dashboard gives these numbers for the past day:

- Google Places API Web Service: 407
- Google Maps Geocoding API: 70
- Google Maps JavaScript API: 30

What could be causing this? How can I get this up and running again, it is killing my application?

Comment: Do you use an API key from this project?

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question because I am in the same position, seemingly well below the quota limits according to the console.

In the developer's console, go to the Dashboard, then click on the Google Places API Web Service. Then in the Quotas tab, scroll to the bottom and you'll see the Requests per Day. Here I was clearly reaching the 1000 requests per day limit, hence explaining the blocking of the requests.

> We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards
>   the daily limit of the associated web service API.*

So it's the `libraries=places` and associated api usage (e.g. autosuggest in the search box) that is triggering this.